# Convert String attributes to numeric values in WEKA

Tags: weka

I am new to weka.. My data contains a column of student name. I want to convert these names to numeric values, over the whole column.
Eg: Suppose there are 10 names abcd ,cdef,xyz ,etc.  I want to pre process the data so that corresponding to each name there is distinct numeric value, like abcd changes to 1 ,cdef changes to 2 ,etc.

Also two or more rows can have same name. So in this case, same name should have same value.

Please help me...

Comment: why would you want to do that? What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: String to Nominal I can understand.  The question is sort of worth answering in the what if the column attribute type is incorrectly chosen, but not what if I arbitrarily want to change it.

Answer (score 5):

Weka supports 4 non-relational attribute types: nominal, numeric, string and date. You can find out more about them in Weka Manual (it can be found in the same folder were you downloaded Weka), chapter "The ARFF Header Section".

You should find out what is the type of the "student's name" attribute (probably string, but could be nominal), and decide what should be the type of the attribute with converted values (numeric, nominal, or string).

There can be 2 scenarios:

(1) If types of the existing and desired attributes are the same (string-string or nominal-nominal, i.e. you only want to change values, not attribute type), you could do so
(a) manually - open the data file in Weka Explorer, and click Edit... button, or
(b) write a small program using Weka's Attribute class functions `value` and `setValue`.

(2) Types are different - Weka attribute types cannot be converted, so you will have to create and insert a new attribute with the converted values, and delete the old attribute. An example of how to create a new attribute can be found at 
http://weka.wikispaces.com/Programmatic+Use#Step.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand, strictly converting names into a "numeric" type doesn't seem like the best approach, within the context of WEKA - WEKA will treat numeric attributes differently than it does "string" or "nominal" attributes (for example, for running certain "attribute selection" algorithms, you can not use "numeric" types - they need to be "discretized" or converted into nominal form).

So, for your case, I think you can convert your "string" names into just "nominal" type using the [StringToNominal](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.stable/weka/filters/unsupervised/attribute/StringToNominal.html) class (this class acts as a WEKA "filter" to help convert a given "string" attribute into an attribute of type "nominal"). This will also take care about the repeating names - the list of "nominal" values for the names (that will be generated after you apply this filter) will contain any given name (that appears any number of times) only one time.

"Nominal" attributes also have the advantage that implicitly, they do have a numeric representation (the index of the value within the set of values; similar to how the "enums" in Java have a numeric index). So, you can utilize that as the "numeric" information corresponding to the names (though as I said earlier, it's probably best to just use it as "nominal" attribute; really depends on your particular use case).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as the one mentioned in the question, and I could "address" it in the following way.

I first applied the StringToNominal filter as mentioned before (don't forget to change the attribute range (from "last" to "first-last")). Once done that, I saved the dataset in LibSVM format, which changes the nominal values to numeric ones.

Then, if you close Weka and open it again, you will have the same dataset with the same number of features but they will be numeric. Now some changes should be done, first of all, normalizing all the numeric values in the dataset, using the Normalize filter. After that, apply the NumericToNominal filter to the last attribute.

Then, you will have a similar dataset with numeric values.

Hope this helps.